# checkbox onCLick function using AJAX

Tags: ajax, checkbox, onclick

My question is simple, I have a contact form with a checkbox in it. What I want is when the user clicks the checkbox, a message to appear on the side. What I will add in future is, when a second checkbox is clicked to change the message, but first I would like to fix this. I saw some similar questions asked, but I still couldnt do it. The code is:

The checkbox inside the form:

```
<input type="checkbox" onclick="check(this);" />
```

This is still in the same file, `contact.php`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(cb)
{
    if(cb.checked)
    {
        $.getScript("clickCheckbox.php");
    }
}
```

and another php which is supposed to be called after a click: `clickCheckbox.php`

```
<?php
    header("Content-type: text/javascript");
    echo 'alert("Clicked!");';
?>
```

What am I not doing right? I am a begginer, so I will apriciate every comment and advice. Thank you!

Comment: you are requesting a php file using `getScript`, while it tries to retrieve a js file, see documentation [here](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/)

Comment: so ,you @BeNdErR mean that instead of  $.getScript("clickCheckbox.php"); i should use $.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: "script",
  success: success
});